# Ошибка JSON.parse при переходе в поле на вторую строчку. Как обойти?

Tags: javascript, json, django

Для построения и инициализации [Metronic Datatable](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/?page=components/datatables/base/row-details&demo=default) использую в коде `JSON.parser`, данные парсятся с джанговской админки и что бы исключить ошибку с переходом на вторую строку - применил функцию `replace`.

```
var dataJSONArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('[массив переменных django]').replace(/\n/g, " "));
```

Но это не работает, когда в джанговской админке в поле notes ввести данные через: `test1 <enter> test2 <enter> test3`  то получаю ошибку `JSON`: переход на новую строку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как побороть эту ошибку. Спасибо. 
Если нужен дополнительный код, предоставлю.

массив, который парсится:

```
[{% for order in orders %} ' + '{"#": "{{ order.id }}","updateUrl":"{% url "staff:order-update" order.id %}","client":"{{ order.client }}", "total":"{{ order.final_price }}","orderNotes":"{{ order.notes }}", "payment":"{{ order.get_payment_gateway_display }}","status":"{{ order.get_status_display }}"}\n' +'{% endfor %}]
```

Comment: приведите пример входных данных

Comment: подскажите каких именно?

Comment: В админке django пользователь вводит комментарии, и если он введет: test1 enter test2 enter test3 то я получу ошибку как на скрине,  если же текст вводиться без принудительного переноса на новую строку, то все ок

Comment: Лечите причину, а не симптомы — соберите нормальный JSON-массив на стороне джанги с использованием питонового `json.dumps` без всех этих ужасных извращений в шаблоне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена с помощью django-фильтра `{{ value|linebreaks }}`
то есть добавить в массив к переменной фильтр:

```
"orderNotes":"{{ order.notes|linebreaks }}"
```

и парсится все отлично.

Comment: И всё же лучше по-нормальному использовать `json.dumps`